# Updating pre-trained Deep Learning model with respect to new data points

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Considering the example of Image classification on ImageNet, How to update the pre-trained model using the new data points. 
I have loaded the pre-trained model. I have a new data point that is quite different from the distribution of the original data on which the model was previously trained. So, I would like to update/fine-tune the model with the help of new data point. How to go about doing it? Can anyone help me out in doing it? I am using pytorch 0.4.0 for implementation, running on GPU Tesla K40C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the output of the classifier (i.e. the number of classes), then you can simply continue training the model with new example images, assuming that they are reshaped to the same shape that the pretrained model accepts.

On the other hand, if you want to change the number of classes in a pre-trained model, then you can replace the last fully connected layer with a new one and train only this specific layer on new samples. Here's a sample code for this case from [PyTorch's autograd mechanics notes](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/autograd.html):

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
# Replace the last fully-connected layer
# Parameters of newly constructed modules have requires_grad=True by default
model.fc = nn.Linear(512, 100)

# Optimize only the classifier
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.fc.parameters(), lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```